# How to find documents using $near method

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I have a geoJSON database like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBadE.png). I need to use `$near` command to filter by giving coordinates. So can you please help me to make this query as well as how to do this in java.

Java code:

```
public BasicDBObject nearestpoint(DBCollection collection, double
longitude, double Latitude, int near_distance) {

    final LinkedList circle = new LinkedList();
    circle.addLast(new double[] {
        longitude, Latitude
    });
    circle.addLast(near_distance);

    BasicDBObject q = new BasicDBObject("loc", new BasicDBObject("$near", new BasicDBObject("$geometry", new BasicDBObject("Point", circle))));
    System.out.println("nearestpoint function done");
    return q;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have nodejs code to use $geoNear. Below is the snippet:

```
db.MYCOLLECTION.aggregate([ { $geoNear: { near: [lon, lat], distanceField: "distance", maxDistance: distance/3963.2,distanceMultiplier:3963.2, spherical: true, limit: 5000} } ], function(err, items){});
```

Where, lon, lat are you coordinates. distance is your distance from current location. This will give distance in miles.